# Within each td/box, how to make it so the header in each box is fixed with scrollable div beneath?

Tags: html, css

I have 9 boxes, I want each box to have a "heading", and scrollable content beneath the "Box n" heading.

Am looking for 1) Ensure the "header" is vertically aligned to the top of each box. 2) The scrollable content takes up the max height of each box.

How do I do this? My HTML is the following:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

table {
  border: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}

div {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        Box1<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Box2</div>
      <div>
        Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        Box3<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Box4</td>
    <td>Box5</td>
    <td>Box6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Box7</td>
    <td>Box8</td>
    <td>Box9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The fiddle I have is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ba5qxzmo/

Box 1 is bad, because the Box1 header text is not "fixed at the top of the box and scrolls with the content. 
Box 2 is my attempt at creating a fixed header, but it messes up the look of the box entirely.
Box 3 and the rest of the boxes also do not have a fixed header.

How can I make it such that each box has a "fixed" header? (Box1, Box2, Box3), with scrollable content (overflow) beneath each of them?

Comment: Do you mean make the "BoxN" text be fixed, and the "Some TExt" after it in a separate scrollable area? Because you'll need to change the HTML to do that.

Comment: That is correct. I want Box 1, 2, 3, 4 text at the top of each box to be fixed. And all the "Some Text" (anything after the text at the top of each box, to be in a scrollable area. My attempt to do this with Box 2 was by separating the individual td to have 2 divs, one for the heading: "Box 1", the other containing everything after it that can be scrolled. The point of the SomeTexts are just to pretend there is a lot of content to show there is an overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your whole content of a cell except heading in a div and make the div as scrollable using `max-height` and `overflow-y:scroll` and set the `height` of `td`, heading and content so that everything will align properly.

```css
html,body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
table {
  border:1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

}
td {
  text-align:center;
  background:red;
  padding:  10px 0;
}

.scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;  
  background:yellow;
}

.heading{
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      
        <span class="heading">Box1</span>
        <div class="scroll">
        Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
        </div>
     
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="heading">Box1</span>
      <div class="scroll">
        Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      
       <span class="heading">Box1</span>
         <div class="scroll">Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br> Some TExt<br>
      </div>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Box4</td>
    <td>Box5</td>
    <td>Box6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Box7</td>
    <td>Box8</td>
    <td>Box9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please *explain* what the solution you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: This is close, though I am looking for 1) Ensure the "header" is vertically aligned to the top of each box. 2) The scrollable content takes up the max-height of each box. (so it takes up as much of the box as possible). On a full screen page with your code, it looks like there is a lot of red space above and below the overflow region.

Comment: @Rolando Not really fair adding requirements after the question has been answered...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I know, I was about to explain my code, but by mistake i press tab and then enter key, and it's posted here.

Comment: I can mark it as correct and create a new question if appropriate, I did not anticipate an answer that was not complete to my question so I added clarification.

Comment: @Rolando I have updated the code, is this what you want?

Comment: Yes! This is exactly it, thank you! Does this make max-height:130px; unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

Take heading on one div and the content in another div, and make the first div position fixed. and give the second div propperty overflow: scroll;
        
            Some text
        
        
            Some text

```
     .heading{
        position:fixed;
      }

     .content{
        overflow:scroll;
      }
```

Comment: position:fixed is bad because it will make the header float over all of the elements. I want to avoid using that if possible. If for some reason I scroll the entire page, the headers will "float" with the scroll of the page.

Comment: If you don't wont header to be fixed on the top, just giv all box overflow:scroll; And your box will be scrolable.

Comment: For clarification, I want the header to be fixed at the top of each box, but not on top of all the elements and is "sticky" to the page.

Comment: Ok, take fixed div in another div and give it height of fixed div, or give it overflow:hidden, then your fixed div will not  be "sticky" to the page.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
    <div class="fixed_parent">
        <div class="fixed">
            Some Heading
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
            Some content
    </div>

 .fixed_parent{
    height:100px; (or if it's depends on height of fixed div and it can changes you can right overflow:hidden; without writhing about height)
  }

 .heading{
    position:fixed;
  }

 .content{
    overflow:scroll;
  }
```